# How to bulk update a particular Tag in Azure on the basis of Subscription, Region and another tag?

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line-interface, azure-powershell, tagging

I need to bulk update a particular tag which is applied on a variety of resources in Azure like VMs, NSGs, AGWs, RGs, so on and so forth. I need to update this tag for all kind of resources on which they are applied. How can I do the same ? I need to filter resources on basis of Subscription, Region and another tag value ? Can I use AZ CLI or Azure Powershell  and if yes, how ? How can I put filter of Subscription, Region and another tag value for bulk tag update ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter with subscription, you need to use [`Set-AzContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/Set-AzContext?view=azps-5.3.0) to set the specific subscription, because azure powershell can just run against one subscription, to see the subscriptions that your logged account can access, you could use [`Get-AzSubscription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azsubscription?view=azps-5.3.0).

Then you can filter with region and another tag value, after getting them, update their tags via [`Update-AzTag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-aztag?view=azps-5.3.0).

```
Connect-AzAccount
Set-AzContext -Subscription "<subscription-id>"
$resources = Get-AzResource -TagName "tag1" -TagValue "value1" | Where-Object {$_.Location -eq 'centralus'}
$Tags = @{"tag1"="value1"; "tag2"="value2";}
$resources | ForEach-Object {
    Update-AzTag -ResourceId $_.ResourceId -Tag $Tags -Operation Merge
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure PowerShell:

```
$mergedTags = @{"key1"="value1"; "key3"="value3";}
Update-AzTag -ResourceId /subscriptions/{subId} -Tag $mergedTags -Operation Merge
```

Original documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-aztag?view=azps-5.3.0

or Az Cli:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/tag?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: yes, But I need to filter the resources on the basis of Region and another tag value, that is the main thing.

Comment: @Chaitanya got it!:
Get-AzResource -TagName "Jira" | ...
or
Get-AzResource -TagValue "Value" | ....
or
Get-AzResource | where {$_.Location -eq "eastus"} | ...

Comment: I wrote a pipeline, cmon. 
powershell works like this, first command to Get something, then pipeline | , then set/update something.

Comment: can you share/post that ?